# Reading an unbounded input stream in Python

Tags: python

I need to read from an unbounded stream, i.e. constantly receiving new information.

Specifically I need to read and match words as they go by.

Are there anyways to continually read and match?

My code so far is:

```
matches=[]
wordsToFind=['foo','bar','donut']
while True:
  s=raw_input()
  for word in wordsToFind:
    if s.find(word)+1:matches.append(word)
  print '\n'.join(matches)
```

I would like an easier way to do this that does not rely on waiting for the input.

That is, the input kind of running in the background while the code reads it.

Is there one, or is this the best option?

The stream is a automated feed of data that I have to read.  The new data can come at anytime though.

I didn't make the stream, and cannot change it.

Comment: Certainly: `while True: read(); match()`

Comment: Please try to be as precise as possible when asking questions. As is, we don't have enough information to answer your question.

Comment: @Steven is it better now?

Comment: Where is this stream coming from? Is the sending automated or manual? How frequently does it need to send you new information?